# OnKeyListener only detects return key

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created the simplest Android project I can in order to test using an OnKeyListener to see what is being typed in an EditText widget. The problem is that the onKey method is only firing for the return key - no others. Based on my code below, what can possibly be preventing the OnKeyListener from working?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setViewListeners();
    }

    private void setViewListeners() {

        EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);          
        EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);

        et1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.i("INFO", "keyCode=" + keyCode);
                return false;
            }
        });
     }
}
```

And the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <EditText
          android:id="@+id/text1"   
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Once again, the only key press for which I get a log statement is the return key ("keyCode=66"). I have also used breakpoints to confirm that that is the only time that code executes. What could my problem be? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should use TextWatcher instead of OnClickListener

```
mPostEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charsequence, int i, int j, int k) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
        @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charsequence, int i, int j,  int k) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
};
```

Comment: Yup, I've gone down that road too.

Comment: Is that because OnKeyListener does not register character keys? The documentation seems to indicate that it listens for any key presses.